# How to add column widget inside a flutter DataTable DataCell?

Tags: flutter

The heights of widgets in a DataTable DataCell can vary:

```
 DataCell(Text('Professor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\n'))
```

[image]

But if you add the data as a Column, the cell overflows. Why? And how to fix it?

```
 DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
            ])),
            // DataCell(Text('Professor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\n')),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
              Text("Professor"),
            ])),
            // DataCell(Text('Professor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\nProfessor\n')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your colum with flexible?

Comment: Yes .. : "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a Align widget."

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your column with SingleChildScrollView.
Here is my solution.

```
DataCell(Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                Text("Professor"),
                Text("Professor"),
                Text("Professor"),
                Text("Professor"),
              ]),
            ),
          ))
```

Comment: SingleChildScrollView only works for people who don't need to see all their data at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            border: TableBorder.symmetric(
              outside: const BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: 0.5,
              ),
            ),
            columnSpacing: size.width * 0.025,
            columns: const [
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('No',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Teams',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('M',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('W',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('L',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('T',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('N/R',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('PT',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('NRR',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Series Form',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Next',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('For',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Against',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ],
            rows: const [
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('William')),
                  DataCell(Text('27')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).